# Quickly sort list of objects to match the order of an array which contains the value of a property

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, collections, ienumerable

I have a method that accepts a `string[]`. It takes this array and sorts it based off a custom algebraic formula we have. This algebraic formula is quite complex and cannot (or should not) be adapted to accept anything other than an `IEnumerable<string>`.

I'm tasked with creating a wrapper function for this method that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` implements an interface exposing the string to be used for sorting.

Based on this, I have created a method that iterates the genetic enumerable, extracts the string and passes the resulting array into our custom sort function.  This works,  but I end up with a sorted array of strings,  completely disconnected from the original `IEnumerable <T>` . How can I sort the `IEnumerable <T>` to match the array of strings returned from our custom sort function?

For example.

```
private IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable<T> objects) where T: ICustomSortable
{
    string[] stringsToSort = new string[objects.Count()];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringsToSort.length; i++)
        stringsToSort[i] = objects.getString();

    stringsToSort = customSortFunction(stringsToSort);

    //somehow sort the objects so that they are in the same order as stringsToSort?
    /*
    The result is valid when:
     objects[0].getString() == stringsToSort[0]
     objects[1].getString() == stringsToSort[1]
     objects[2].getString() == stringsToSort[2]
      ...
     objects[n].getString() == stringsToSort[n]
    */
}
```

EDIT: The strings retrieved from the `customSortFunction` may not be unique.  This means that two `objects` whose strings are the same, should both exist in the result. While the ordering of `objects` with the same string value is irrelevant,  they should remain in place when referencing the result as a whole.

Comment: Do you need to use customSortFunction() as a whole? Can you compare two string? Like `bool customCompare(string1, string2);`?

Comment: No. I have to use the custom function.  And I have to pass it the array as a whole.

Comment: OK. I presume that's because of the performance reasons? Because you can easily implement `customCompare()` function by calling `customSortFunction()` and comparing the pairs before and after sorting. (A pair is a list after all, a 2-element list.)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a mapping from the object string value to the object itself. Something like

```
IDictionary<string, T>
```

Just create this mapping (before or after sorting), and after sorting is done based on their string values, create a new sorted list of T, by iterating through the (sorted) string list and using the mapping to get the corresponding T.

EDIT: Based on the comment that the string values may not be all distinct, all you need to do is to create a mapping from the string to a set/list of Ts. Something like,

```
IDictionary<string, IList<T>>
```

[A] While you are looping through `IEnumerable<T>`, (1) if you see a new (string) key, create a new list and add the owner T for the string, and (2) if you find a key that is already in the dictionary, retrieve the list, and append the new owner T into the list.

[B] After sorting is done, go through the sorted string/key list, and find the corresponding Ts (one or more), and create a new list of Ts by consecutively appending the Ts.

This is not the most elegant way (a better way is obviously to use some kind of comparators), but it's straightforward and will get the job done.

Comment: I didn't specify,  but I will edit my questions. While unlikely,  the strings may not be unique.

Comment: I think this approach could still be pursued, but you'd have to create an alternative key type that implemented equality using [Object.ReferenceEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx). That way different string instances with the same value would not be equal in the dictionary. Just keep an eye out for that old dog [String.Intern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The only problem I see in this algorithm (other than the fact that it may not be the most efficient one) is that the sorting may not be stable. If the original string sorting algo is not stable, then this is not a problem But, if the original string is stable, then you will lose that property by doing this one to many mapping.

Comment: If you rely on reference equality, there is no longer a one to many mapping.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. OP has the requirement of using `customSortFunction()` _for strings._ Strings are immutable and the same strings will generally have the same references (in most runtimes).

Comment: There are absolutely no reason why same  (as in `==`) strings will have same references... And based on ... interesting requirement of using string array the sorting code may as well create clones of each string so none of strings will match by reference equality. Strings constructed at run-time (which is very likely the case for function that builds string from an object) are not automatically interned as performance cost of lookup will likely be too high for one-time created strings.

Comment: The point is not that all strings of the same values will have the same references. The point is, they _can_ have the same references. I see your point of strings not likely being interned at run time, but that's not something you can rely on while designing an algorithm.